# Eclipse plugin for COBOL

Tags: eclipse, plugins, editor, cobol

I am working on a IDE plugin in Eclipse, for COBOL. I've forked a version of  kewl-deus's CopylineParser and have added things to it. In most of the older COBOL source code I encounter a sequence number/change key in the first six columns of the source file. ex:

```
000000 IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
000000 PROGRAM-ID. SOME.
000000 PROCEDURE DIVISION.
000000     DISPLAY "HELLO WORLD".
000000     STOP-RUN.
```

Is there a way to ensure that when user presses enter key a new sequence number/Chnagekey will be automatically inserted? 
ex:

```
000000 IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
000000 PROGRAM-ID. SOME.
000000 PROCEDURE DIVISION.
000000     DISPLAY "HELLO WORLD".
CR2587     DISPLAY "NO MORE".
000000     STOP-RUN.
```

The eclipse plugin source can be seen at https://github.com/ravsas3/CopylineParser

When i tried to use `set` it was causing problem with existing outline feature hence I dropped that idea. Currently I am stripping the leading sequence no/Changeid in every line in the document itself and then setting the stripped text to the document with the following code, this works fine for smaller code but is failing for a bigger code (say > 60000 LOC ).

```
public CobolProgram getModel()
{
    if (this.model == null)
    {
        IEditorInput input = this.getEditorInput();
        IDocumentProvider prov = this.getDocumentProvider();
        IDocument doc = prov.getDocument(input);
        CobolParser parser = new CobolParser();
        System.out.println("This is where everything is loaded!!"+input.getName()+doc);
        doc=Stripcolumns(input.getName(),doc);
        CobolProgram program = parser.parse(input.getName(), doc);
        setModel(program);
    }
    System.out.println("getModel...");
    return this.model;
}

public IDocument Stripcolumns(String filename,IDocument doc) {
    int lineCount = doc.getNumberOfLines();
    int lineNo=0;
    IRegion region = null;
    String textline = null;
    String displayText = "";
    System.out.println("going to strip columns...");
    while (lineNo < lineCount)
    {
       try { region = doc.getLineInformation(lineNo);                                         } catch (BadLocationException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
       try { textline = doc.get(region.getOffset(), region.getLength());                      } catch (BadLocationException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
       try {   displayText=displayText+textline.substring(CobolParser.COLUMN_PARSE_OFFSET-1)+"\n";} catch (Exception e) { displayText=displayText+"\n"; }           
        lineNo++;
    }
    System.out.println("Done...");          
    return doc;
}
```

My question is "is there any better/faster way to do this?".(i mean stripping the 6 columns.) I agree I haven't thought of the process for "saving" this redacted document.

[image]

Comment: I attempted to build an ISPF editor as an Eclipse plug-in.  I created an SWT editor with separate areas for the sequence number (columns 1 - 6), the continuation character (7), the source (8 - 71) and the IBM sequence number (72 - 80).  The project became too complicated for me when I had to replicate most of the Eclipse editor classes to handle a fixed format file like a mainframe Cobol source code file.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the six-digit number in the *sequence number area* was, and I'm being serious, that if you dropped your `deck` of `punched cards` you could get them back into order.

The sequence number area does not have to contain a sequence number. Sometimes it gets used for marking who added/changed that line last.

A compiler may be told to respect the sequence number and report if there is an out-of-sequence number (duplicates are allowed due to `copybook's, which means they are allowed for everything) or report on whether there is any information other than blanks.

You could try to find out how IBM's Eclipse-based Rational Developer product deals with it. The Eclipse code-base came originally from IBM.

A quick look at Wikipedia has reference to COBOL as being supported via plugin. You could try to track down that (or those) and see how they do it (you may find references to eclipse in the GnuCOBOL project at SourceForge.Net).

The way I'd do it, assuming Linux/Unix/Windows with source-management through some "version control" product is to find out what the user uses the sequence number area for. If for nothing (even if present) or for something which is better served by their version-control, I'd blank out the sequence number column (replacing the first six characters by six blanks) as a once-off, for all programs, and commit those changes. Then just proceed as normal.

What would perhaps be useful for a COBOL Eclipse plugin would be to have an option to show the seventh column of the source (the `indicator area`) as the first column whilst editing. Since the first six columns are (or can be) ignored whilst editing, and option to not even show them might be useful.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Bill Woodger, but the six columns are used as an id of changes done. hence for tracking changes it is required. i cannot remove that. yes, i will try Rational Developer (can you point please me in how to get info on that). Yes, iam tryig to remove first 6 columns, but the stirping  is taking time.

Comment: An internet search will get you loads about Rational Developer. If the sequence number area is being used to track changes, then you don't want to put sequence numbers in it. Where is your COBOL source being held?

Comment: yes...i've wrongly stated it to be sequence number but i am working on a process where i will put the change id (like CR2456) whenever user adds a new line. And i am searching for Rational Developer too. I have a doubt. in Eclipse editor reconciler can i find the key that has been pressed? ( whichtriggered this reconsile process)

Comment: If you need a change-number (and bear in mind you will only ever have six characters available) then rather than as each line is changed or added, I'd look to do it at the "end" of an edit session for a program. Can you update your question to include the change from sequence to change comment and say what OS you are using and where the source is held and what "version control" it is under (if any) please?

Comment: yes...i am looking at "Serena PVCS Version Manager" on a HP-UX machine (Micro-Focus Server Express). Yes i've thought about "end of edit session" too...but that way ill have to have a huge memory usage (for finding out the change and tag them)...will put the code...i am currently working on some changes in the code, will update it once done. Thank you for the counsel :).